Microsoft Flow Graph API Call to Assign License to New User
I am trying to use a Graph API call in a Flow that will assign a license when a new user is created.  I am trying to build out the license assignment, and I am getting the error "error": { "code": "Request_BadRequest", "message": "Specified HTTP method is not allowed for the request target.",
I am not sure what is incorrect.  The application I have being used had ReadWrite.All permissions for both Directory and Users.  Here is the full JSON output and input.
Any ideas?
Input:
{
    "uri": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/67a9cbf3-d55b-47b3-b0d2-be1ba01f683d/assignedLicenses",
    "method": "POST",
    "authentication": {
        "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
        "tenant": "Tenant ID",
        "audience": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
        "clientId": "Secret ID",
        "secret": "*sanitized*",
        "type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth"
    },
    "body": {
        "addLicenses": [
            {
                "disabledPlans": [],
                "skuId": "f30db892-07e9-47e9-837c-80727f46fd3d"
            },
            {
                "disabledPlans": [],
                "skuId": ""
            }
        ],
        "removeLicenses": []
    }
}

Output:
{
    "statusCode": 405,
    "headers": {
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
        "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000",
        "request-id": "fe8722cd-c0ab-462b-aa01-4271924efb28",
        "client-request-id": "fe8722cd-c0ab-462b-aa01-4271924efb28",
        "x-ms-ags-diagnostic": "{\"ServerInfo\":{\"DataCenter\":\"West US\",\"Slice\":\"E\",\"Ring\":\"4\",\"ScaleUnit\":\"001\",\"RoleInstance\":\"BY1PEPF00003AA0\"}}",
        "x-ms-resource-unit": "1",
        "Date": "Thu, 09 May 2024 20:25:32 GMT",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Content-Length": "267"
    },
    "body": {
        "error": {
            "code": "Request_BadRequest",
            "message": "Specified HTTP method is not allowed for the request target.",
            "innerError": {
                "date": "2024-05-09T20:25:33",
                "request-id": "fe8722cd-c0ab-462b-aa01-4271924efb28",
                "client-request-id": "fe8722cd-c0ab-462b-aa01-4271924efb28"
            }
        }
    }
}

I expect and license to be assigned to the user, but I am getting a Request_BadRequest error

You are calling wrong endpoint
"uri": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/assignedLicenses",

correct one is https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/assignLicense
"uri": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/assignLicense",

https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/user-assignlicense?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
